# What piece is this and what is its purpose?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I am very confused on what this is. The only numbers on it are 8-01 and I searched for this and nothing comes up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 14):

We call them [space binoculars](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30304). They're like binoculars, but in space!

Comment: They are supposed to look like the [Macrobinoculars](https://www.yourprops.com/Skywalker-Macrobinoculars-replica-movie-prop-Star-Wars-A-New-Hope-1977-YP75646.html) that Luke uses as well as some other similar "large fancy binoculars" from the series.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Really?  Because it doesn't look anything like the item in the link you posted.

Comment: They come in Star Wars sets. I know it’s not an exact visual match, but rather a lego interpretation of “bulky high tech” binoculars.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Once you consider the constraints required to have a minifigure actually hold them up to their face, they actually seem remarkably close .That said, they also showed up in a few Rock Raiders sets the same year they were first introduced, and have been used in a couple of police-themed World City sets as well.